# Como puedo abrir una sección en ciertos navegadores al dar click en el menú

Tags: html5

Estoy teniendo algunos detalles al momento de visualizar mi sitio web, el problema es que al dar clic a un menú y me muestre una sección no me lo muestra en ciertos navegadores como Chrome y Microsoft Edge pero en Firefox no tengo ningún problema, he buscado información y es porque algunos navegadores no tienen habilitado el `smoothScroll` pero no encontrado alguna solución.

```html
<section class="navbar navbar-fixed-top custom-navbar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mi página web</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">INICIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work" class="smoothScroll">CONOCEME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">PORTAFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing" class="smoothScroll">SERVICIOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">CONTACTO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<!-- home section -->
<section id="home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <h3>WEB DESIGN / WEB DEVELOPMENT / SOCIAL MEDIA</h3>
        <h1>DIGITAL TEAM</h1>
        <hr>
        <a href="#work" class="smoothScroll btn btn-danger">What we do</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll btn btn-default">Talk to us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- work section -->
<section id="work">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="section-title">
          <strong>01</strong>
          <h1 class="heading bold">WHAT WE DO</h1>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
        <i class="icon-cloud medium-icon"></i>
        <h3>WEB MARKETING</h3>
        <hr>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteu sunt in culpa qui officia.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
        <i class="icon-mobile medium-icon"></i>
        <h3>UI &amp; UX DESIGN</h3>
        <hr>
        <p>Digital Team is free responsive Bootstrap v3.3.5 layout from <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.tooplate.com" target="_parent">Tooplate</a>. Images are from <a rel="nofollow" href="http://pixabay.com" target="_parent">Pixabay</a> free photo website.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1s">
        <i class="icon-laptop medium-icon"></i>
        <h3>ECOMMERCE</h3>
        <hr>
        <p>You can edit and use this template for your websites. Please tell your friends about Tooplate. Thank you for visiting our website.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1s">
        <i class="icon-compass medium-icon"></i>
        <h3>MOBILE APP</h3>
        <hr>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteu sunt in culpa qui officia.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1s">
        <i class="icon-chat medium-icon"></i>
        <h3>SOCIAL MEDIA</h3>
        <hr>
        <p>You can easily change icons by looking at <a href="https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/how-to-use-and-embed-an-icon-font-on-your-website" target="_blank">ET Line Icons</a>. Excepteu sunt in culpa qui officia. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1s">
        <i class="icon-browser medium-icon"></i>
        <h3>RESPONSIVE LAYOUT</h3>
        <hr>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteu sunt in culpa qui officia.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yo uso Edge y me funciona

Comment: Deshabilité el `smoothScroll` y me sigue funcionando

Comment: Ya lo tenia deshabilitado pero al llamar una sección lo hace medio brusco claro si funciona, pero con el  `smoothScroll` lo hace mas suave.

Comment: Entonces es el menú el que no funciona o es el smoothScroll??? Si es lo último debes ajustar tu pregunta